# Node js memory keep rising

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, v8

I have application (sending messages to endpoints) running on Node-Js
for time to time I need to restart the application in order to clean
"heapUsed"

but if I run Garbage collector manually (global.gc()) I see it's clean the memory
but while Garbage collector run automatically its not (the "heapUsed" keep rising)

I add --trace_gc --trace_gc_verbose node param to insure GC run automatically and found to following log:

```
...
    [49366]   548769 ms: Scavenge 54.0 (163.5) -> 39.0 (163.5) MB, 5.5 ms [allocation failure].
    [49366] Memory allocator,   used: 167396 KB, available: 1331740 KB
    [49366] New space,          used:    681 KB, available:  15702 KB, committed:  32768 KB
    [49366] Old pointers,       used:  22615 KB, available:  63597 KB, committed:  92601 KB
    [49366] Old data space,     used:  12236 KB, available:  11704 KB, committed:  24378 KB
    [49366] Code space,         used:   3335 KB, available:   2564 KB, committed:   5976 KB
    [49366] Map space,          used:   1027 KB, available:   5010 KB, committed:   6174 KB
    [49366] Cell space,         used:     17 KB, available:     98 KB, committed:    128 KB
    [49366] PropertyCell space, used:     26 KB, available:     37 KB, committed:     64 KB
    [49366] Large object space, used:      0 KB, available: 1330699 KB, committed:      0 KB
    [49366] All spaces,         used:  39939 KB, available:  98715 KB, committed: 162089 KB
    [49366] External memory reported:   -299 KB 
...
```

I also use Node js [gc-heap-stats](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gc-heap-stats) and [gc-profiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gc-profiler)
to insure GC is running and found is run also for Scavenge and Marksweep algorithm

I monitor
freemem  using `OS.freemem()`
totalmem using `OS.totalmem()`
memUsage using `process.memoryUsage()`
result look like this:

```
  "freemem": 509698048,
  "totalmem": 17179869184,
  "memUsage": {
    "rss": 281284608,
    "heapTotal": 212272640,
    "heapUsed": 184643248
  }
```

After running Garbage collector **manually** (with global.gc()):

```
  "freemem": 443863040,
  "totalmem": 17179869184,
  "memUsage": {
    "rss": 276410368,
    "heapTotal": 207112960,
    "heapUsed": 57413400
  }
```

I also take heapdump before and after check it with chrome dev tool and found no conclusions about any memory leak or strange behavior

so why memory keep rising?

Answer (score 0):

Doing garbage collection is work that the process needs to do, which means it has a performance cost. V8's GC is carefully tuned to give you a good tradeoff between doing as little GC work as possible, while still freeing memory quickly enough. 163MB is not a lot of used heap, so it will just take a little longer until the GC becomes more active. Don't worry about it, less time spent in GC means more time available to run your code :-)

If you *want* V8 to use less memory (which means spending more time doing GC earlier, and running into out-of-memory earlier if required memory exceeds the limit you set), you can use the `--max-old-space-size` flag to configure the "old space" part of the heap (in megabytes). (I'd recommend not to touch the other spaces.)

You probably also want to update your Node.js. The `--trace-gc-verbose` output indicates that the V8 in there is more than two years old; many things have been improved in this time.

Comment: This info is from my local MAC. in production the totalmem and heapUsed are much bigger and much closer  heapUsed is rising above totalmem and I got out of memory. I know about the --max-old-space-size prop but I try to avoid using workarounds and to get the bottom of this and understand the reason (--max-old-space-size is my last resort). For now we have to work with very old Node-js version 0.12.6 because other dependencies.